# DrupalVM ubuntu 14.04 vagrant provision error 'packages cannot be authenticated'

Tags: virtual-machine

I ran `vagrant provision` and I get this error:

```
at: apt-get install -y -qq software-properties-common python-software-properties

error message:
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
python-software-properties
```

When I try run `sudo apt-get update` on the VM I get these errors.

```
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/InRelease
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/InRelease
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'us.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Note that there is no `InRelease` file in these directories:

http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/

http://old-releases.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease

I am using:

Host machine:
OS: Ubuntu 16.04 x86_64
vagrant: Vagrant 1.8.5

VM:
box 'geerlingguy/ubuntu1404' (v1.1.3) for provider: virtualbox

config.yml:

```
vagrant_hostname: iemp.local
vagrant_machine_name: iemp

vagrant_box: geerlingguy/ubuntu1404
php_version: "5.6"
drupal_major_version: 7
drush_version: "7.x"

php_packages:
  - php5
  - php5-apcu
  - php5-mcrypt
  - php5-cli
  - php5-common
  - php5-curl
  - php5-dev
  - php5-fpm
  - php5-gd
  - php5-sqlite
  - php-pear
  - libpcre3-dev
php_conf_paths:
  - /etc/php5/fpm
  - /etc/php5/apache2
  - /etc/php5/cli
php_extension_conf_paths:
  - /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d
  - /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d
  - /etc/php5/cli/conf.d
php_fpm_daemon: php5-fpm
php_fpm_conf_path: "/etc/php5/fpm"
php_fpm_pool_conf_path: "/etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf"
php_mysql_package: php5-mysql

build_makefile: false
build_composer: false
build_composer_project: false
install_site: false

vagrant_synced_folders:
  - local_path: ./
    destination: /var/www/drupalvm
    type: nfs
    create: true
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up reinstalling the host machine, Virtual Box and Vagrant. It seems like I broke something by manually deleting the Virtual Machine via the Virtual Box Admin Interface.

With the new installation and the same configuration it worked perfectly.

I suggest using `vagrant destroy` to delete your virtual machine files.